# Python: iterating through a list and printing x elements at a time

Tags: python

Let's say I have a list:

```
n1 = [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]
```

and I want to iterate through the list and print the first three elements, then the next three elements of the sequence, up to the end. That is, I want this to be output:

```
20, 21, 22

21, 22, 23

22, 23, 24
```

How can I do this efficiently in Python?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
n1 = [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]
listing = [', '.join(map(str, n1[i:i+3])) for i in range(len(n1)-2)]
for l in listing:
  print(l)
```

Output:

```
20, 21, 22
21, 22, 23
22, 23, 24
```

Comment: This answer could be improved by an explanation.

Comment: You don't need to create a new list for this. A generator expression is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to chunk your list and print. A generator function helps make this efficient, explicit and adaptable. Courtesy of [@Ned Batchelder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/312464/9209546) (upvote there).

```
def chunks(l, n):
    """Yield successive n-sized chunks from l."""
    for i in range(0, len(l) - (n-1)):
        yield l[i:i + n]

n1 = [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25]

for lst in chunks(n1, 3):
    print(' '.join(map(str, lst)))

# 20 21 22
# 21 22 23
# 22 23 24
# 23 24 25
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to print out chunks of length 3, you can use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) here:

```
n1 = [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]

for x, y, z in zip(n1, n1[1:], n1[2:]):
    print(x, y, z)
```

Which Outputs:

```
20 21 22
21 22 23
22 23 24
```

If you want to print out any sized chunks, you can use [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.deque):

```
from collections import deque
from itertools import islice

def chunks(lst, n):
    queue = deque(lst)

    while len(queue) >= n:
        yield list(islice(queue, 0, n))
        queue.popleft()

n1 = [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]

for x in chunks(n1, 3):
    print(*x)

# 20 21 22
# 21 22 23
# 22 23 24
```

Comment: That works for three elements. What if there were more? Like 100?